# Bypass the yes/no prompt in 'apt-get upgrade'

Tags: command-line, apt, alias

In order avoid typing out all of the apt-get commands when updating my computer I have made a simple alias command to do it. But I really want to be able to just type in my alias and let it do its thing and not have to wait to for the yes/no prompt to type in "y". Is there a simple way to bypass this prompt or maybe add "yes" in the alias somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automating apt-get install with --assume-yes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448358/automating-apt-get-install-with-assume-yes)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Sure, although I have never tried it as an alias but it should work:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

Comment: I will edit and remove the -y from update if it bothers you One Zero. :)

Comment: This doesn't work in Trusty.

Comment: Doesn't work with grub override conf question.

Comment: For grub override conf question you have to set this in front of it `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get...`

Comment: @saitam - thanks.... the DEBIAN_FRONTEND variable is exactly what _I_ was looking for! Kodos.

Comment: This is NOT ENOUGH.

Answer (score 14):

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confold' --force-yes -fuy dist-upgrade
```

To clarify `Dpkg::Options::='--force-confold'` from the man-page:

> **`--force-confold`**: do not modify the current configuration file, the new version is installed with a `.dpkg-dist` suffix. With this option alone, even configuration files that you have not modified are left untouched. You need to combine it with **`--force-confdef`** to let dpkg overwrite configuration files that you have not modified.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What does this command do and how does it work?

Comment: Nice to see the deeper answer to this question, thanks Vadim.

Answer (score 3):

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
```

This updates the packages, upgrades the packages, removes unused packages, then removes old versions of packages.

You can copy paste that into:

```
nano -w yourscript.sh
```

then

```
chmod 777 yourscript.sh
```

then

```
./yourscript.sh
```

So long as you use `su` before all those steps, which I always do.

Comment: This answer goes... too far. He might not want to delete old/unused packages. Also I don't think you should ever use chmod 777 if it can be avoided. And I believe in Ubuntu the recommended way is to use apt-get rather than apt.

Comment: Agreed, important to answer the actual question, not go further.

Comment: @AndreasHartmann Agreed. That script is a security risk if put on 777. Use chmod  u+x instead (only sets the executable bit for the file owner)

Comment: First, you can also put `sudo` in front of each command and second, you can write a script that automatically generates `yourscript.sh` which I could provide if there is interest for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it quietly and then get a notification when it's all done. The downside to this is you will only see errors reported and will not see what is updated.

```
sudo apt-get update -qq && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -qq && echo "All up to date now!" && notify-send "All up to date now!"
```

Answer (score 1):

[@wojox answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/118027/830570) is correct, but you can take the alias even further for more functionality. I have been using this for quite some time now without issue. This will perform the upgrades (confirming with `-y`) and then testing to see if a reboot is required. If a reboot is required, you can do so by pressing `[ENTER]`, or cancel and reboot later by pressing `[CTRL+C]`. If no reboot is required, the alias finishes letting you know so.

My alias is `sur` for `sudo upgrade reboot`, but feel free to name it what you choose. Add the following to your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias sur='sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && if sudo test -f /var/run/reboot-required; then read -p "A reboot is required to finish installing updates. Press [ENTER] to reboot now, or [CTRL+C] to cancel and reboot later." && sudo reboot; else echo "A reboot is not required. Exiting..."; fi'
```

You can continue to chain more commands if you would like to do more with the same alias. Here is the complete alias from my `.bashrc` that will also remove unused packages:

```
alias sur='sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && if sudo test -f /var/run/reboot-required; then read -p "A reboot is required to finish installing updates. Press [ENTER] to reboot now, or [CTRL+C] to cancel and reboot later." && sudo reboot; else echo "A reboot is not required. Exiting..."; fi'
```

I actually stumbled across this thread while checking to see if there is an option to skip the prompt for configuration file overwrites, which was provided in [@Vadim's answer above](https://askubuntu.com/a/388606/830570)! My new alias is this:

```
alias sur='sudo apt update && sudo apt -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && if sudo test -f /var/run/reboot-required; then read -p "A reboot is required to finish installing updates. Press [ENTER] to reboot now, or [CTRL+C] to cancel and reboot later." && sudo reboot; else echo "A reboot is not required. Exiting..."; fi'
```

I then push this new `.bashrc` file to each of my managed servers simply with:

```
while read HOST; do scp .bashrc username@$HOST:/home/username; done < managedhosts.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a function has been the most straightforward, universal method I've found.

I've personally never gotten the `update && -y upgrade` to work correctly. Some distros have a problem with a single command (or alias) using the `&&` operator and `-y` argument together.

```
function update ()
{
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt -y upgrade
}
```