# Automatically enter input in command line

Tags: command-line, input

I'm running a script that it requests entering 'y' on each operation, I am looking for a solution like `$ ./script < echo 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy'` to pass all my inputs in one time.

Comment: Sometimes `-f` option works well with certain commands.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

There is a command created specifically for that case: `yes`

```
$ yes | ./script
```

What this does is connect the output of `yes` to the input of `./script`. So when `./script` asks for user input it will instead get the output of `yes`. The output of `yes` is an endless stream of `y` followed by enter. So basically as if the user is entering `y` for every question of `./script`.

If you want to say no (`n`) instead of yes (`y`) you can do it like this:

```
$ yes n | ./script
```

Note that some tools have an option to always asume `yes` as answer. See here for example: [Bypass the yes/no prompt in 'apt-get upgrade'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118025/bypass-the-yes-no-prompt-in-apt-get-upgrade)

---

Other methods to enter input:

If you know exactly how many `y` your script is expecting you can do it like this:

```
$ printf 'y\ny\ny\n' | ./script
```

The newlines (`\n`) are the enter keys.

Using `printf` instead of `yes` you have more fine grained control of input:

```
$ printf 'yes\nno\nmaybe\n' | ./script
```

Note that in some rare cases the command does not require the user to press enter after the character. in that case leave the newlines out:

```
$ printf 'yyy' | ./script
```

For sake of completeness you can also use a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells):

```
$ ./script << EOF
y
y
y
EOF
```

Or if your shell supports it a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings):

```
$ ./script <<< "y
y
y
"
```

Or you can create a file with one input per line:

```
$ ./script < inputfile
```

If the command is sufficiently complex and the methods above no longer suffice then you can use [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Here is an example of a super simple expect script:

```
spawn ./script
expect "are you sure?"
send "yes\r"
expect "are you really sure?"
send "YES!\r"
expect eof
```

---

Technical nitpick:

The hypothetical command invocation you gave in your question does not work:

```
$ ./script < echo 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
bash: echo: No such file or directory
```

This is because the shell grammar allows a redirect operator anywhere in the command line. As far as the shell is concerned your hypothetical command line is the same as this line:

```
$ ./script 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy' < echo
bash: echo: No such file or directory
```

That means `./script` will be called with the argument `'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy'` and the stdin will get input from a file named `echo`. And bash complains since the file does not exists.

Comment: I get a `cannot enable tty mode on non tty input`. Would you know a workaround for that?

Comment: When I try the `printf` trick with a `run` file that I need to automate the installation process of, all that happens is I get an error message saying `Warning: Tried to connect to session manager, None of the authentication protocols specified are supported`, and the script opens in a new terminal and asks me to enter my input manually as usual. This is happening on Debian by the way. Any suggestions?

Comment: need more details. too big for comments. please ask a new question with all the details. you can put a link here.

Comment: nothing works with 'vagrant destroy' on centos

Comment: Wicked easy! Works on the Google Cloud Beta SQL data imports! Much appreciated!

Comment: I just learned that actually /bin/yes can send any argument given, like `yes` `no` or `maybe` not only single characters.

Comment: Does the command `$ printf 'yyy' | ./script` send 3 `yes` three times, or is it a syntax to send one yes? I assume it is the first option since it is in context of sending the `yes` command multiple times, but I have not found a way to test it.

Comment: @lesmana Is there any way to edit the shell file to have the script itself enter `yes` or `no` for us?

Comment: Hi @Lesmana, `melos` command gives me `StdinException: Error getting terminal echo mode, OS Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device, errno = 25` when I pass output of `yes` to it. Is it possible to fix this?

Command: `$ yes 33 | melos run analyze`

Comment: to big for comment. please post is as a new question. feel free to drop link to new question here.

Comment: `printf y\n` without quotation marks will print `yn` whereas single and double quoation marks as in `printf 'y\n'`work and print a new line.

Comment: `expect` never worked for me. For what is worth: `$ ./script < inputfile` worked wonders for me automating my openvpn3 login ;)
Thanx

Answer (score 14):

Use the command `yes`:

```
yes | script
```

Excerpt from the man page:

```
NAME
       yes - output a string repeatedly until killed

SYNOPSIS
       yes [STRING]...
       yes OPTION

DESCRIPTION
       Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or 'y'.
```

Answer (score 10):

Some things (`apt-get` for example) accept special flags to run in silent mode (and accept defaults). In `apt-get`'s case, you just pass it a `-y` flag. This does completely depend on your script though.

If you need more complicated things, you can wrap your script in an expect script. expect allows you to read output and send input so you can do pretty complicated things that other scripting wouldn't allow. Here's [one of the examples from its Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect#Basics):

```
# Assume $remote_server, $my_user_id, $my_password, and $my_command were read in earlier
# in the script.
# Open a telnet session to a remote server, and wait for a username prompt.
spawn telnet $remote_server
expect "username:"
# Send the username, and then wait for a password prompt.
send "$my_user_id\r"
expect "password:"
# Send the password, and then wait for a shell prompt.
send "$my_password\r"
expect "%"
# Send the prebuilt command, and then wait for another shell prompt.
send "$my_command\r"
expect "%"
# Capture the results of the command into a variable. This can be displayed, or written to disk.
set results $expect_out(buffer)
# Exit the telnet session, and wait for a special end-of-file character.
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: This can't be used it with a `.sh` shell script, right? Or is there a way?

Answer (score 7):

In the shell script you can also use the following trick of spawn, expect and send

```
spawn script.sh
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
send "yes"
```

However in the above scenerio you will have to give the phrase you are expecting to get while you execute the script for more examples go to the following link

[Expect within Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575702/help-with-expect-within-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 3):

You can supply user input to your script with `cat`, from a text file, piped to your script with `bash` like this:

```
cat input.txt | bash your_script.sh
```

Just put your desired user input into your input.txt file, whatever answers you want - y, n, digits, strings, etc.

Comment: @WebComer How should I write the `input.txt` file? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this may not be a very elegant solution but if you write your options in a separate file and then pass it as an input to the script, it would work as well. So if you create a new file with all your options (call this file as 'options.in'), then you can easily run your script with `./script.sh < options.in` and edit/create different options files as suitable.

Comment: How should I write the `options.in` file? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

I was writing a bash script with Dialog and needed this to happen automatically also. I did this and it worked like a charm.

```
# -Wy force signaturewipe (if exists)
echo "y" | sudo lvcreate -W y -n $lvName -L "$lvSize"G /dev/"$svg" >> $nfsUtilLog
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write the expect script as follow:

```
$ vi login.exp
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh username@machine.IP
expect "*assword: "
send -- "PASSWORD\r"
interact
```

And run it as:

```
$ expect login.exp
```