# Automatically send file input to command using expanded variables

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, input

I need to send some credentials defined in a file to a vpn connection command which is waiting for username and password to be entered when executed. There is a similar requirement to my question [Automatically enter input in command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line).

The following solution provided does work for me too:

```
printf 'username\npassword\n' | /usr/sbin/openconnect -i vpn0 ...
```

(executed inside a shell script). But I need to pass the credentials contained in a file (`env_properties`) and loaded as environment variables. I'm loading the file content using the following command:

```
[ -f env_properties] && . env_properties
```

The content looks as follows

```
export VPN_USERNAME=myUsername
export VPN_PASSWORD=myPassword
```

However, such a construct doesn't work anymore:

```
printf "${VPN_USERNAME}\n${VPN_PASSWORD}\n" | /usr/sbin/openconnect -i vpn0 ...
```

It seems that the input isn't recognized correctly for whatever reason. And neither this command

```
printf "/usr/sbin/openconnect -i vpn0 ... < env_properties
```

with a modified file content containing only plain username and password, each in a new line. Same applies to the *here document* solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
printf "${VPN_USERNAME}\n${VPN_PASSWORD}\n"
```

try this:

```
printf "%s\n%s\n" “$VPN_USERNAME” “$VPN_PASSWORD”
```

Comment: thx for your reply, but it didn't work out either. It seems like the variable expansion somehow distorts the input strings or so

Answer (score 0):

Silly me! The input file has carriage returns which the Linux system of course cannot deal with. After removing them the print command I've posted now works.