# Executing Command in Bash Script that requires Input

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to create a bash script that will run a command then send some input after. More specifically I need to run the command "php artisan migrate --seed" then send an input of "yes"

Comment: This may help: [Automatically enter input in command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you have a php script that contains some input handle like this `fopen ("php://stdin","r");`, if you want a bash script to 'type in' a 'yes', you may simply use pipe redirection:

```
#!/bin/bash
# some commands
echo "yes" | /usr/bin/php /path/to/php/script.php
#
```