# Automatically enter user input several times to command stdin

Tags: command-line, bash, openssl, certificates, stdout

I need to perform a conversion of digital certificates from pfx to pem on an external application from which I can run system commands. I can do this from CLI by using the command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path/to/cert.pfx -out path/to/cert.pem
```

This will prompt the user for the certificate password, and secondly, for a passphrase.

I've tried the solution provided here:
[Automatically enter input in command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line)

And it is not working for me. So, if I try (note the line breaks):

```
printf 'the_password\nthe_passphrase\n' | openssl pkcs12 -in path/to/cert.pfx -out path/to/cert.pem
```

It will still ask me for the password and passphrase. I also tried using `echo`, without success.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Following Level9's advice, I've tried using openssl options, like this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path/to/cert.pfx -out path/to/cert.pem -password pass:the_password -passout pass:
```

I've tried both providing a passphrase and not, like in the example. Now it generates the pem file, but if I try to open it from my file system, just to check if it's correct, then I'm asked for the password, but it will not accept the one I provided in the command line.

Comment: maybe this can help you: [How to generate an openSSL key using a passphrase from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294689/how-to-generate-an-openssl-key-using-a-passphrase-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the options for specifying passwords in openssl.

```
openssl pkcs12 -help
```

If that doesn't work for you then try the "expect" utility.

```
sudo apt install expect
```

Comment: I've tried doing a research in the command options (see my edit section in the question), but I don't seem to get it working. Since you knew there's something provided by the openssl options, could you tell me if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: I'm not in position to try this now but if password of pfx is pfxpass then try enter `openssl pkcs12 -in path/to/cert.pfx -out path/to/cert.pem -passin pass:pfxpass -passout pass:` Of course you can specify a password after the : in the last command if you do want a password of the pem-file.

Comment: Now it seems to work. Thanks a lot! I still don't know about the difference of the -password -passin and -passout options and why the "pass" prefix to the value (I'm not savvy on either digital certificates or Linux CLI), but I won't touch anything! :D