# apt-get install with --assume-yes is still prompting me to install dependencies

Tags: apt

I am trying to write a bash script to install a list of software. I am using `--assume-yes` to get past the prompts.

This following line somehow doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties --assume-yes
```

If I try to `apt-get` without `--assume-yes` it works but the prompt asks me to:

```
please [Enter] to continue or ctrl+c to cancel adding it
```

How do I add <kbd>Enter</kbd> as a command when running `apt-get install` instead of using `--assume-yes`?

Comment: `please [Enter] to continue or ctrl+c to cancel adding it` it only appears if you are trying to add a PPA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bypass the yes/no prompt in 'apt-get upgrade'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118025/bypass-the-yes-no-prompt-in-apt-get-upgrade)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Your problem is that the option should be before the packages, not after, this is the correct syntax:

```
apt-get <options> command package=version/release
```

So, for it to work it should be:

```
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install python-software-properties
```

apt-get is forgiving when mixing up command and options, but to err on the safe side, you should always use the options before the command and never put options or commands after the name of the package.

Answer (score 75):

Add `-y` flag to `apt-get install <package-name>` command like below, you won't get any prompt while installing packages.

```
sudo apt-get install -y <package-name>
```

From `apt-get --help`

```
-y  Assume Yes to all queries and do not prompt
```

Comment: @PeterMortensen they do the same thing. From the man page:`-y, --yes, --assume-yes
           Automatic yes to prompts`

Comment: Note that this may not be enough and you may also need to add `-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"` to your commands. See https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/ for details.

Comment: @TTimo Wow! 6 days after you posted that comment, I come along and find that's exactly the answer I needed!! If I could upvote your comment more I would!

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer with additional options.

Answer (score 7):

For another silent and effective way as follows :

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq python-software-properties < /dev/null > /dev/null
```