# How to do `sudo apt install aptitude` but auto default to install package maintainer version?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, aptitude

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 server edition.

When I run

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

I get the below prompts

```
Configuration file '/etc/systemd/resolved.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
```

Can I avoid all the prompts and just default to package maintainer's version without being asked?

I will get two kinds of prompts. The command line one as you see above, and the one with slightly more GUI with the pink background asking similar question.

I just want to install with just the package maintainer's version regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you automate answering to questions in `apt`, you do that for all prompts at once. It is not possible to selectively disable prompts. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448358/apt-get-install-with-assume-yes-is-still-prompting-me-to-install-dependencies): `-y` or `--yes` or `--assume-yes` will automatically answer `-y` to all prompts.